# VBA saving picture from url without opening new tabs

Tags: image, vba, download

I have a list of url that links to pictures. There is one url per row. If you click the url it will open a new tab in google chrome and download it. Wich is good since i want to dowload the pictures. But after a few (50 or some) there is to many tabs and the whole thing just freeze and shut down.

So basicly is there a way to have something that will download the pictures without opening new tabs in google.

Here is what i am using

```
Sub OpenHyper()

numRow = 2

Do While ActiveSheet.Range("D" & numRow).Hyperlinks.Count > 0
    ActiveSheet.Range("D" & numRow).Hyperlinks(1).Follow
    numRow = numRow + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

and this is the type of link i am opening

http://depot.ville.montreal.qc.ca/vues-aeriennes-obliques-1960-1969/VM94-B001-001.tif
http://depot.ville.montreal.qc.ca/vues-aeriennes-obliques-1960-1969/VM94-B001-002.tif

thanks

Comment: Use the WinAPI `URLDownloadToFile` function?

Comment: I never used this function, i am going to take a look in it as to how i can make it work for url in excel cell for 7000 cells. But i am fairly new to all this so any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Yes i can use IE, but when i do, IE prompt me to see if i want to open or save, so it doesnt download automaticly

Comment: hmmm I'm having trouble getting that function to work for these files. They are served in a weird way, forcing a download from the browser when "clicked".  Not sure that function will work here.  I have the same problem with IE that you are having.

Answer (score 0):

OK. I've heard about this but have not tried to use it yet. There is an API that you can use with Chrome. Download it and install it.

https://code.google.com/p/selenium-vba/

The enable reference to the SeleniumWrapper Type Library in the VBProject.

**NOTE** You may need to change some setting in your Chrome Browser to prevent it from "opening a new tab". In my browser, when I navigate to those URLs it downloads directly without opening a new tab, the files just appear in the list of downloads in the bottom of the browser.

Once you've done that, then this code should work (but it is not likely to work for other URLs which do not *automatically* download the file).

```
Sub DownloadFiles()
'Files will be downloaded directly to your "Downloads" folder or whatever is
' your default folder for downloading content from the internet.
Dim numRow As Long
Dim url As String
Dim chrome As SeleniumWrapper.WebDriver

numRow = 2

Set chrome = New SeleniumWrapper.WebDriver

chrome.Start "Chrome", "http://google.com", False

Do While ActiveSheet.Range("D" & numRow).Hyperlinks.Count > 0
    url = ActiveSheet.Range("D" & numRow).Hyperlinks(1).Address
    chrome.Open url
    numRow = numRow + 1
Loop

chrome.Close
Set chrome = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works perfectly after adding a little tweek because if it opens Url to fast, they start to accumulate and then chrome opens new tabs to keep track. So i just added a delay in the loop : Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10")) . And now its all good

Comment: Cheers. Do consider marking this answer as "Accepted" if it has helped solve the problem :)